# can't load too big html file when grab

Tags: php, html, mysql

here's my problem. i have tried to grab html file. but this file have 350 mb size. and when i tried to load it with file_get_contents and using DOM it not showing any output. just a white background. when i tried with small file, it's works. why should i do.

```
<?php

// error_reporting(E_ALL);
// ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('max_execution_time',5000);

$source=file_get_contents("C://xampp/htdocs/Champion/machine-
logs/LogPrinting03/RIPLOG.HTML");
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($source);

echo $source;

?>
```

Comment: It's probably `memory_limit` by default it will be 64mb or 128mb depending on the server. You need to enable error reporting so you'll see the error and not only a white page!

Comment: oh yes, it because memory_limit, i tried in local server. so what the solution.

Comment: You can change it localy like you did with the `ini_set` or globaly for all your sites by configuring the **php.ini** file, try the code in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to increase the memory limit in your PHP.ini or locally for your app using the following code :

```
// I'm setting the memory limit to 1024M, but it should work with less memory
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');
// Enable error reporting - TO BE REMOVED BEFORE YOU GO TO PRODUCTION
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('max_execution_time',5000);

$source=file_get_contents("C://xampp/htdocs/Champion/machine-
logs/LogPrinting03/RIPLOG.HTML");
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($source);

echo $source;
```

Comment: but it say, Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted.

Comment: Which means your scripts needs more than 512mb, if you have enough memory try with 1024mb

Comment: You welcome, don't forget to remove the 3 lines for error reporting if you will push this code to your production environnement ;)